# Directory.CreateDirectory error on linux using C#.net core - access path denied

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, console-application

I cannot create directory on linux ,it is giving error. The error is "access to the path is denied"
I am using following code in c#.net core

```
 if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
 {
   Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
 }
```

Please help me on this...

Comment: Try to run this program with more rights. Or change the rights on the folder were you want to create a directory. PS: I don't know if you are catching these exceptions, but this can be usefull.

Comment: Hi,How to run program with more rights.Can you send me the sample code

Comment: I have an .Net core 3.1 console applicaiton.
Directory.CreateDirectory() is giving error on linux.
Error: Access to the path is denied", I have given the following path,
Home/ProjectName/Log/

Comment: I think is more wise to change the rights on ProjectName and its subdirectories. https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/ here is an explanation how this works in Linux. Edit: here is a link about run VS as administrator, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/user-permissions-and-visual-studio?view=vs-2019. As the article says, you should avoid this.